# How to remove redundant .so files in Android libs directory

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I have nearly developed an Android application, the APK file size is 12MB.
The file organization looks like this:

`libs
  |-- arm64-v8a
  |-- armeabi
  |-- armeabi-v7a`

To support video chat, I copied `video_chat.so` (4MB) into `armeabi` directory.

Now APK file size is 20MB and the file organization looks like this:

`libs
  |-- arm64-v8a
  |-- armeabi
  |   |- video_chat.so
  |
  |-- armeabi-v7a`

It works well on `sony ES350`, but crashed on other cellphone, such as `smartisan T1`. After searching, I copy `video_chat.so` from `armeabi` to `armeabi-v7a`, then file oranization looks like this:

`libs
  |-- arm64-v8a
  |-- armeabi
  |   |- video_chat.so
  |
  |-- armeabi-v7a
      |- video_chat.so`

It works, but APK file size expand to 20MB. 
So my question is, how to avoid copying this redundant `video_chat.so` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all sub directories of `libs` except for `armeabi`, and the most of x86 mobile phone is compatible with arm.

Comment: Can you please share the procedure how to remove all sub directories